# Restart Sikuli script after error - calling from command line

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

If I run a script manually from the IDE and it errors out somewhere, I am able to just hit Run again and it continues from where it left off. If I call a script from command line, is there any way to do this?

Running it from command line does not open the IDE, it just starts running the script and if it fails, I am not notified in any way, nor do I see a way to restart the process. I am using command line because it is an automated task that runs on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go another route as I found out this is not possible.